# USB port not working, while shutdown and network manager are misbehaving

Tags: 12.04, updates, xubuntu, network-manager, shutdown

I use an Acer Aspire One with Xubuntu (12.04).
Last night I installed a few updates, only the security ones because it was late.  It finished OK with a message about needing to restart for the changes to be effective.

Today I have 3 issues:

The first is that network manager is misbehaving.  The network icon is 2 little arrows.
Hovering over it gives the help text: `Networking disabled`.
Clicking on it says: `NetworkManager is not running...` and a right click shows a limited menu (3 lines) with only one option not greyed out: `Edit connections`.

If I check with service network-manager start, it says start: `Job is already running: network-manager`. I tried to stop then, restart. The networking icon hasn't changed, but the messages are different: Hovering over it is still the same (`networking disabled`) but with left click it says `No network devices are available` (in grey) and I can click on `VPN connections`. While on right click it gives the same menu as previously, but now the greyed out `Enable networking` has a *tick* in front of it.

I searched online, and the closest I found was [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2116855). Although I am not running Mate.

The second problem is that when I click on the *Shutdown* icon I get an error window:

```
Unable to perform shutdown
Shutdown command failed
```

And I can only click on Quit or hit enter, which brings me to a login screen. Attempts to shutdown from there fail too. I can however shutdown by typing `sudo shutdown -P 0` in a Terminal.

Finally, the USB ports do not work, in as much as I cannot mount anything inserted.  The memory slot does not work either.  As I only noticed this last issue after posting my original question I will go and search online some more to see if I can revert to the pre-upgrade situation without going online nor using a USB port.

Many thanks

anne

Answer (score 1):

OK, I am a fool.
The solution was to run Update Manager again.  It complained about some half-unpacked packages then about the lack of internet connection so that the update could not be completed.  This seems to have cleared something, maybe reverted the unfinished update.
I then attempted a restart, which failed (same as when I could not shutdown) but upon loging in from the login screen I could then initiate a succesfull restart and my little laptop is back up and running.

I wrote that I was a fool because although I thought I could shutdown after running Update Manager and it would finish its business when I next turned on, I should have opted for the proposed restart then, and none of this would have happened.